# App Icon Missing in Google Drive Manage Apps

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, chrome-web-store

I have an android app that connects to Google Drive. I created a Chrome Web Store listing for this app using following manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "App Name",
  "description": "App Description",
  "version": "2.4",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "container": ["GOOGLE_DRIVE"],
  "api_console_project_id": "ID",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  }
}
```

When I checked Google Drive - Settings - Manage Apps, for this particular app all other details showing except App Icon.

Please advise how to proceed on this?

[image: App Icon Missing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has come up with an updated approach to provide application details in Google Drive as Chrome Web Store is shutting down.

In the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), once you enable Google Drive API, you can provide your app details in the Drive UI Integration tab from the Drive API page.

Where you can provide your app description and icons.

Happy Androiding....

Answer (score 1):

Your "icon_128.png" must be existing inside the compressed folder on where you placed your manifest file, so that it would return the image as your icon no matter where you place your application.

You can also go to your [Chrome Webstore Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard?hl=en), go to your app and click Edit. That will open a window where you can upload your 128px icon.

Comment: I have done this and icon is showing in chrome dashboard.

Comment: When I upload the zip, icon not showed in application details in Web Store. Then I need to manually browse the icon and upload it in Web Store.